# Error with uniqueness validator in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem  with my validation for a model. I want to ensure that for a particular Website that each Inventory name will remain unique.

When I add this to my model:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => { :scope => :website }
```

I get this error:

`TypeError - Cannot visit Account::Website:`

The relationship is setup like this:

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website, :class_name => 'Account::Website'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea but using this instead:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => { :scope => :website_id }
```

Fixes it.

Anyone able to share why?